# React TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance on Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I try to write my PrivateRoute components, but when I try to work I get

```
"TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance"
```

on declaration. I spent a lot of time trying to understand it.
Here is my code:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/auth";
import  Login  from "../pages/Login";

export const PrivateRoute = ({component, ...options}) => {  <------- ERROR LINE

  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(AuthContext);
  const finalComponent = state.isAuthenticated ? component : Login;

  return (   
     <Route {...options} component={finalComponent} />
  );

};
```

and I call on my app with:

```xml
<AuthProvider>

       <Router>

        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </Router> 

    </AuthProvider>
```

Comment: Can't seem to replicate - it works on my end.

Comment: working file at my end also. Could you provide the error log

Comment: joshi-yogesh example error in this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-caertn